# How to integrate?

Tags: calculus, integration

The [exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvwzF.jpg) is

$\Large{\int \frac{e^{\ln [\cos(\sqrt x)\cdot \tan(\sqrt x )]}}{\sqrt x}} \, \large{dx}$

How to present?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: as a quick hint, e^ln(x) = x

Comment: I guess the third take will have the proper alignment between line of fraction, exponent and integral sign...

Answer (score 4):

We have $\cos(x) \tan(x) = \sin(x)$, and $e^{\ln{ (\text{blah}) }} = \text{blah}$, so after simplifying in this manner, we get $\displaystyle \int \frac{\sin( \sqrt{x})}{ \sqrt{x}} \ dx$, which can be evaluated with a substitution $u = \sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since ${ e }^{ \ln { x }  }=x,\cos { x } \tan { x } =\sin { x } ,d\left( \sqrt { x }  \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  } $ we have

> $$\int { \frac { { e }^{ \ln { \left( \cos { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right) \tan { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  }  }  \right)  }  } }{ \sqrt { x }  }  } dx=\int { \frac { \cos { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right) \tan { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  }  }  }{ \sqrt { x }  }  } dx=\\ =2\int { \sin { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  }  } d\left( \sqrt { x }  \right) =-2\cos { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  } +C$$